# .Net Core AJAX Post Null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried a variety of configurations but cannot get data to pass to the controller. What am I missing?

```
public class PartsImport
{
    public string companyID { get; set; }
    public string partsCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string subCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string partNumber { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string description2 { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string cost { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string vendorID { get; set; }
    public string mfg { get; set; }
    public string companyLocationID { get; set; }
}
```

The controller. At this point the partsImport is null.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ImportPartsData([FromBody] IEnumerable<PartsImport> partsImport)
    { 
      ...
    }
```

Here is the ajax request along with some sample json data. Tried to submit both versions but continue to get null when it gets to the controller.

```
var data = { "partsImport": [{ "companyID": "57", "partsCategoryID": "205", "subCategoryID": "", "partNumber": "1", "name": "PVC Conduit 1/2 inch by 10 Feet", "description": "1/2 inch", "description2": "", "quantity": "1", "cost": "2.40", "price": "3.10", "vendorID": "", "mfg": "", "companyLocationID": "156" }, { "companyID": "57", "partsCategoryID": "205", "subCategoryID": "", "partNumber": "2", "name": "PVC Conduit 3/4 inch by 10 Feet", "description": "3/4 inch", "description2": "", "quantity": "1", "cost": "3.03", "price": "3.91", "vendorID": "", "mfg": "", "companyLocationID": "156" }] };

//var data = [{ "companyID": "57", "partsCategoryID": "205", "subCategoryID": "", "partNumber": "1", "name": "PVC Conduit 1/2 inch by 10 Feet", "description": "1/2 inch", "description2": "", "quantity": "1", "cost": "2.40", "price": "3.10", "vendorID": "", "mfg": "", "companyLocationID": "156" }, { "companyID": "57", "partsCategoryID": "205", "subCategoryID": "", "partNumber": "2", "name": "PVC Conduit 3/4 inch by 10 Feet", "description": "3/4 inch", "description2": "", "quantity": "1", "cost": "3.03", "price": "3.91", "vendorID": "", "mfg": "", "companyLocationID": "156" }] ;

$.ajax({
        url: "/purchasing/ImportPartsData",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {

        },
    });
```

Comment: Easiest way is to remove `"partsImport":` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `{"partsImport":}`.Change your code like below:

```
var data = [{ "companyID": "57", "partsCategoryID": "205", "subCategoryID": "", "partNumber": "1", "name": "PVC Conduit 1/2 inch by 10 Feet", "description": "1/2 inch", "description2": "", "quantity": "1", "cost": "2.40", "price": "3.10", "vendorID": "", "mfg": "", "companyLocationID": "156" }, 
            { "companyID": "57", "partsCategoryID": "205", "subCategoryID": "", "partNumber": "2", "name": "PVC Conduit 3/4 inch by 10 Feet", "description": "3/4 inch", "description2": "", "quantity": "1", "cost": "3.03", "price": "3.91", "vendorID": "", "mfg": "", "companyLocationID": "156" }
           ];
```

Result:
[image]